# Highlight item onClick - React.js

Tags: reactjs

Add underscore to category-item onClick and remove underscore for any other item. Found some answers on how to do this with only two components, a "item-container-component" and "item-components". But i have three components involved. This is what I hope to achieve:

[image]

*Archive-component (mother component)*:

```
class Archive extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      category: "",
      activeIndex: 0
    }
    this.filterHandler = this.filterHandler.bind(this);
  }

  filterHandler(tag, index){
    console.log('INDEX: ' + index);
    this.setState({
      category: tag,
      activeIndex: index
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const myInit = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    fetch("/getProducts", myInit)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({products:data});
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('ERROR!!! ' + err.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <div className="archive-container">
          <div className="archive-wrapper">
            <CategoryContainer
              filterHandler={this.filterHandler}
              products={this.state.products}
              activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
            />
            <br/><br/>
            <ProductContainer
              products={this.state.category.length
                ? this.state.products.filter((prod) => prod.category === this.state.category)
                : this.state.products.filter((prod) => prod.category === 'Paint')
              }
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

*Category-container component*:

```
class CategoryContainer extends Component {

  render(){
    const categories = [...new Set(this.props.products.map(cat => cat.category))];

    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="filterList">{
          categories.map((cat, index) =>
            <CategoryItem
              key={index}
              index={index}
              category={cat}
              active={index === this.props.activeIndex}
              handleClick={() => this.props.filterHandler(cat, index)}
            />
          )
        }</ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

*Category-item component*:

```
class CategoryItem extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <li
          className={this.props.active ? 'active' : 'category'}
          onClick={this.props.handleClick}
        >
            {this.props.category}

        </li>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Yelp! 
M

Comment: Passing the function through props of 3 components is no fun and usually a sign that you should try another way.  I would either try to work within the component and its internal state (perhaps using evt.target and refs) or bring Redux on board if you think this project is going to be more complex and have further challenges like this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Thanks for your comment. I edited my question to my latest attempt, do you have any idea why that isn't working? The project will not get more complex than this .. I'm at the finish line, and I will dive into redux for my next project, but I'm trying to get this one to work without it

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing the issue, but `this.state.products = data;` shouldn't be used. `this.setState({products:data});` should be used instead. Also remove `this.setState(this.state);`

Comment: @sissonb I need to have that in my fetch from my database, otherwise the database is not set to state ..

Comment: @sissonb Sorry I understood now! Thank you, much better for the database, still doesnät do any difference for my categorys .. :(

Comment: Can you log the `this.props.products` array in the CategoryContainer's render method and show us the data's model

Comment: @sissonb Yes I added a screenshot!

Comment: @sissonb Oh damn you're right. I console.log:ed *this.state.products* from the archive component so you would see the datamodel, but when I tried to console.log *this.props.products* from my **Category-container-component** it shows nothing. I updated my question with both screenshots and updated code

Comment: I adjusted the question to the correct answer. My issue was an error with the categories.map() function in CategoryContainer component. @SurajKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a li tag for which you want to change the color of.
you could probably try something like this.

`<li id="colorChangeOnClick" class="redColor" onclick={this.onClickFunction()}></li>`

Then in your react class you can have the on click function with parameters e:

```
onClick(e) {
   //This would give you all the field of the target
   console.log(e.target.elements);
   // you can do all sorts of Css change by this way
   e.target.element.class="newGreenColor";
}
```

Also make sure to make a state or a prop change otherwise the page would not render again.